# I can't access values stored in tables sqlite3 ,it give undefined error

Tags: discord.js, node-sqlite3

My task is to get the values stored in the row , but I am not able to access the values . It gives undefined error .

```
var idOfOrderQuery = 123;
db.serialize(function(){
db.run("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = ?",idOfOrderQuery,function(err,row)){
console.log(row.id);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using better-sqlite3 you should try db.prepare instead of db.run

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using better-sqlite3